# what is the development tool of this GUI

Tags: windows, user-interface

I have a light/simple app (Winodws GUI), I want to know what is the development tool of this app? most of the app's files are as bellow.

I am newer to app development, I expected to know like "this app is developed by WPF&C#, Electron&Js, Qt&C++" this message. I am not sure if this message could be idenfied from the files shown

btw, there is an .exe with them

[image]

Comment: I don't see how you can expect people to tell from names of compiled library files and code. Perhaps you can glean something from inspection of the files themselves.

Comment: Where is the .exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to say exactly because these libraries are pretty common.

msvcp140 implies that the base is C++ developed with Visual Studio 2015 or later.

d3d* means something there is using Direct3D as well (could be Chromium). EGL/GLES is more graphics stuff, probably used by Chromium.

The presence of Chrome* means it is either using Chromium to display some web content or the entire app is HTML/Javascript based like Electron.

You should inspect the .exe in a hex editor. And a [strings tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings).

Use something like [WinSpy](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy) to inspect the main application window. What is the class name?

Comment: I used the WinSpy to the app.exe, I got "Chrome_WidgetWin_0" and "Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWDN 'Chrome Legacy Window'" info, I search it, seems has relationship with "Chromium Embedded Framework" and I am looking into it,(sorry for late reply)

Comment: Probably Electron... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)